# wget and strange file extensions

Tags: file, download, wget

I am having a bit of trouble grabbing some files that have a strange file structure. What do I mean exactly? http://downloads.cloudmade.com/americas/northern_america/united_states/district_of_columbia#downloads_breadcrumbs

Look at that example. I want to start at the root of the site and recursively grab all the files that end with *.shapefile.zip. wget appears to treat this as two separate files ending in .shapefile and .zip. Anyone have some wget goodness to help me get started on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively wget specific file types with:

```
wget -A 'shapefiles.zip' -r <url>
```

Although I don't think .shapefiles.zip is an extension of .zip but more that site's naming conventions